# Is Oktoberfest in Munich a dog-friendly event?

Tags: munich, pets, oktoberfest

We are thinking of stopping in Munich on our way to Italy from Scotland on the 4th October (the last day of Oktoberfest this year [2015]).

As Oktoberfest will be on, we were wondering if it's something we'll be able to attend with our dog (breed Eurasier, a medium sized dog).

I realise the tents may normally be quite busy - but our dog is fairly well accustomed to these environments.

- Are dogs generally permitted anywhere?
- Are they permitted in the tents?
- Do other people bring their dogs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't say definitively that animals are not allowed however:

- Animals are not allowed in tents - [Official Oktoberfest website](http://www.oktoberfest.de/en/article/About+the+Oktoberfest/About+the+Oktoberfest/Info+and+tipps+for+your+beer+tent+trip/2223/)

> Dos and Don’ts inside the tents
>
> You may not take food or beverages into the tents. You can take
>   cigarettes with you, but it's forbidden to smoke inside the tent. Of
>   course also any kinds of weapons are not allowed. **Animals may not
>   enter the tent**. There is a control of bags at the entrance of the
>   tents. We advise to store bigger sized bags at the baggage store at
>   the underground station Theresienwiese.

- On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oktoberfest)

> In 2010, as a "measure to public safety", a dog and animal ban was put
>   into place. 2012 brought the banning of glass bottles after the
>   increase in number of injuries and cuts.

- Horses are known to pull coaches of beer from the brewers to the Oktoberfest grounds, so there probably isn't an absolute ban on animals on the grounds.  But they probably don't permit pets.  A quick Google suggests only service animals are allowed.
- There is a [dog contest](http://www.lschamber.com/oktoberfest/dogcontest/) which suggests there may be some areas where dogs are allowed.
- From experience, I don't recall seeing any casual owners with their pets at the event.  (However my memory of the event may have been affected by alcohol).

Comment: Thanks for the research and your own recollection (as foggy as it may be) :) We may need reconsider this idea then.

Answer (score 12):

Update for 2016:

**[No.](http://www.oktoberfest.de/de/article/Oktoberfest+2016/Service/Hunde,+Gluten,+Souvenirs+-+Noch+mehr+Fragen+zum+Oktoberfest/3621/)**

> Darf mein Hund mit auf das Oktoberfest? - Einfache Antwort: Nein. Das Mitführen von Hunden ist auf der Wiesn nicht gestattet. Außerdem tut man den Tieren bei all dem Trubel mit einem Wiesnbesuch in den allermeisten Fällen auch keinen Gefallen.

Google translate [edited by mts]:

> Can I take my dog to the Oktoberfest? - Simple answer: no. Dogs are not allowed at the Oktoberfest. Moreover, with all the hustle and bustle that comes with an Oktoberfest visit, in most cases you are not doing the animal a favor.

Comment: Great answer and +1. I have edited the google translate to make it sound slightly less German. I also would like to underline that it is borderline abuse to bring a pet to such an event.

Answer (score 4):

Octoberfest in Munich is definitely not dog friendly.
They will allow service dogs into the grounds with no problem.  But some beer tents will not allow your service dog in.